# How to add SSL certificates using AWS console on a ALB spun up by alb-ingress-controller AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-elb, kubebuilder

I have a requirement where I need to maintain multiple public domains to point to our server,
so I use alb-ingress-controller which spins up an ALB and also allows me to pass a 25 cert ARNS in certificateArns annotation,
However if I add any new SSL certificate to the ALB spun up by alb-ingress-controller via AWS console, the K8s controller reconciler removes the certificate that I manually added.

An ideal way for me would be to get the ALB spun up by alb-ingress-controller, but for me to still be able to add the SSL certs to this ALB via AWS Console/API.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

I tried working on the alb-ingress-controller project but it's a big one and I have got a timeline :-)
Hope to get help out of the community.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using kubectl annotate, creating a dynamic patch always appending all certificates there is no other way.